# Angular animation doesn't work if I change the variable state through setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to make an animation changing the opacity of three arrows (I want the user to slide down on my web), so If I want this to happen automatically and repeatedly since the web loads I use a setInterval inside ngOnInit. This method changes the variable state properly, but even if the variable state changes, the animation only works if I use an event like (click)="showArrows" instead of setInterval.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-photo-and-name',
  templateUrl: './photo-and-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photo-and-name.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animateArrows', [
      state('inactive', style({
        opacity: '1'
      })),
      state('active', style({
        opacity: '0.5',
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('400ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('400ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class PhotoAndNameComponent implements OnInit {
  arrowsState: string = 'inactive';
  interval: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.showArrows, 2000);
  }

  showArrows() {
    this.arrowsState = this.arrowsState === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active';
    console.log(this.arrowsState);
  }
}
```

```
<div class="arrows" [@animateArrows]="arrowsState">
    <mat-icon class="arrow">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon class="arrow">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon class="arrow">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Why doesn't it work using setInterval or what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such scenario try using CSS animation with class, rather than using angular animation. Angular animations comes handy when you have changing state on any event, like loading a page, or clicking a button.

For something that is repeating css has better options to acheive the same functionality.